# Installing Ubuntu 13.04 repartitioning problem

Tags: installation, 13.04, partitioning

I wish to install and dual boot Ubuntu 13.04 on my computer but I have encountered the following problem:
[image: ISSUE]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXe85.jpg

If it isn't obvious, I am using ubuntu from the CD, not from my drive. I am trying to install it on my HD. Don't think I am trying to install ubuntu in ubuntu.
If all current partitions are removed... do I lose or erase all of my files when doing so?

I can't just go forward to install now because the following happens:
[image]

What can I do? I just want to run Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 8, but the option wasn't available. Please be as descriptive as possible, have mercy on this Ubuntu noob.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you'll need to boot Windows 8 -> Right click on Computer -> Manage -> Disk Management -> Shrink your Windows partition to desired amount you want to give Ubuntu.

Then you'll need to boot using Ubuntu Live CD and use the space just cleared up by partitioning it into "/" (Root) "swap"  and /home  partitions. Give about 10 GB to the root, 1 GB to Swap partition and the rest to home.

Reply back in case any more information is needed. Welcome to Ubuntu!

Comment: Uh oh, I cannot shrink unfortunately. According to Windows the available shrink space is 0! What can I do to solve this? Or will making a new partition in Ubuntu delete my files? (While I install it, I get the option of repartitioning everything, removing all old partitions.)

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet (I wish reputation worked between stackoverflow and askubuntu). Akshar is right.

The problem is that Windows decides to place files all over the partition, not just at the beginning and fill to the end. The resize partition system inside Windows does NOT move files to another part of the partition that is empty, so if it sees files very near the end, it just gives up. Running defrag used to fix this, but since Windows Vista it doesn't always decide to move things from the end of the partition.

Here's a post on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2087466) that might help.

Comment: Once you reach 200 reputation on one site you get a bonus of 100 on every other site :)